# karatelabs example https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/examples/gatling with gradle does not run

Tags: gradle, karate

gives below error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mock.CatsKarateSimulation
I have even setup my own project with karate + galting +gradle and getting same issue as simulation class not found. i am using Intellij and running gatling task provided in build.gradle.

Comment: sorry I just ran it locally and it works fine. follow this process if you are still stuck: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue